# Bash for loop on two arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop

I have two arrays that I need to iterate over but I can't figure out how to get the combination of both arrays...

```
declare -a things=(
"apple"
"cider"
"OJ"
)
declare -a numbers=(
"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"5
"6"
)


for i in "${things[@]}"; do
  echo $i $numbers
done
```

---

```
Expecting:
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
apple 5
apple 6
cider 1
cider 2
cider 3
... etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare -a things=(
"apple"
"cider"
"OJ"
)
declare -a numbers=(
"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"5"
"6"
)


for i in "${things[@]}"; do
  for number in "${numbers[@]}"; do
    echo "$i" "$number"
  done
done
```

Comment: You should quote the variables in the echo command: there may be whitespace or globbing characters in the array **elements**. (obviously not here, but in general)

Answer (score 2):

To get that output, you need to loop only first array and use `printf`:

```
declare -a things=("apple" "cider" "OJ")
declare -a numbers=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6")

# loop thru 1st array and use printf to print all values from 2nd
for i in "${things[@]}"; do printf "$i %s\n" "${numbers[@]}"; done
```

```
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
apple 5
apple 6
cider 1
cider 2
cider 3
cider 4
cider 5
cider 6
OJ 1
OJ 2
OJ 3
OJ 4
OJ 5
OJ 6
```